# the coating may peel off/may be peeled off

Tags: word-usage

Which is right to say?

The coating may peel off.
The coating may be peeled off.

The context is I mean to say that the coating of a product may come off due to a long-time use.

Comment: They mean different things. Both are grammatical.

Comment: To amplify Jim's comment: In "the coating may peel off", "may" is equivalent to "might". In "the coating may be peeled off", the "might" meaning is still possible, but a more likely meaning is that you have permission to peel off the coating.

Comment: If I mean to say that the coating of a product may come off due to a long-time use, which one is right?

Comment: Broadly, "peel off" means it might somehow *fall* off of its own accord while "be peeled off" means it might be scraped off, as by a fingernail or pen-knife.

Answer (score 2):

They have different meanings.

Saying 'The coating may peel off' gives the coating agency.  It will peel off by itself.  Presumedly over time and/or with exposure to weather.

'The coating may be peeled off' means it is possible for someone/something to peel the coating off.  It could also mean that the coating might have already been peeled off.

There are many ways to interpret the two sentences, beyond just the two meanings of may (is possible vs. might happen).  Context is required for a definite reading.

Comment: Context: The coating of a mattress cover may come off (by itself) if the mattress is used for a long time.

Comment: In that case, only the first makes sense.

The second means that it would be possible for someone to take the cover coating off, or that the cover coating has already been taken off.

Comment: Hey! It sounds like you're writing an information sheet for a product.  If your company needs translation services, perhaps they should pay someone instead of soliciting free advice from well-meaning strangers.

Comment: I am the translator being paid for the job. In non-English speaking countries like where I am, translation companies often hire people who do not have high proficiency in English like myself. I am trying to learn as well as do the job. If I am told with certainty that this is ill-will, I'll stop posting such questions.

Comment: Please don't feel bad about asking, arguments could be made for either case.

On the one hand, you're improving documentation for what sounds like a safety issue.

On the other hand, your employer is trying to cheapskate their way out of paying for a job that a skilled worker could do.

I personally feel you should keep asking these questions to improve your ability, but at the same time maybe you should feel a tiny bit bad about profiting from free labour :) ?

Comment: Well, I do feel bad about my not good enough ability and the company not being able to hire enough skilled workers. It might be hard to believe but there is a real shortage of skilled translators here for my native language and English.

Comment: Haha, you mustn't feel bad personally!

It doesn't make sense to say you don't have access to skilled translators when you're soliciting advice from people on other continents.

But none of this is any of your concern, it's your employer's.

I for one am glad that you are getting it right rather than guessing.  I tried reading the manual for my microwave the other day and I could barely understand it.  If all translators were as conscientious as you I think the world would be a better place :).

Comment: That unfortunately is how things really are (manuals). Anyway, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score -1):

... he coating of a product may come off due to a long-time use

As in:

> Due to prolonged use, the protective coating may peel or wear off'

Comment: This doesn't clarify the difference between the two phrases the OP suggested.